# Ignore some rows when using INDEX function on a PivotTable

Tags: excel, indexing, pivot-table, excel-2013

In Excel 2013 I am using an INDEX function to populate a column with ticker symbols that appear in a pivot table. I find that when I do this it is also pulling in the categories that each ticker appears under - for example "Consumer Discretionary". I do not want to pull the category in at all. I only want a list of the tickers.

How would I be able to do this? Maybe INDEX is the incorrect Excel function to use.

Comment: Can you post the data you are working with so we can see why this is occurring?

Comment: I believe I am using the tabular format. Perhaps my PT format is not correct. When you say indexing on the 2nd column you mean I should get the tickers into the 2nd column instead of the first? How would I do that?

Comment: @BradyK How would I do that? Sorry -- I am relatively new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Andrei post the data from your excel sheet... Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have something as on the left, which can be changed to as in the middle by clicking in the PT, DESIGN > Layout - Report Layout, Show in Tabular Form. The subtotals might then be removed for a result as on the right:

[image: SO26362244 example]

The row labels may be repeated ("filled in") under Field Settings, if desired.